# Trying to open another form in Access based on a field in the current form

Tags: sql, ms-access, dynamic, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a form that's just a list of descriptions (desc.) of other forms. Right now, when you click on a desc., the appropriate form opens; but it's done through a series of if statements in a macro. This isn't going to scale well once more forms are created.

I have a table that has the desc. and the form that is supposed to go to. I want to write a script that uses this table to open the new form based on the desc. clicked, but not using if statements. The end goal is to be able to just add a row to the table for any future forms that are created without making changes to the script or form. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Use [Dlookup](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/domain/dlookup.php) with the description to get the form name

Comment: Yes, this is possible. We created a table of report names, what group was allowed to run them, and a related table that specified what run-time parameters should be available. When you clicked on a report name in a list (that your group had access to), you were presented with a dynamically created list of filters.  In your case, build the VBA to work off your table, and you never need to change the code (well, maybe never is too bold!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a combo box whose row source is a query which selects the form description and name fields from your table.

The combo will have 2 columns.  You can set the width of the form name column to zero if you want to present only the form descriptions.  If you make the form name column the combo's bound column, you can reference it conveniently in a `DoCmd.OpenForm` statement.  For example, you could have a command button whose click event opens the form which is currently selected in the combo ...

```vb
DoCmd.OpenForm Me.YourComboName.Value
```